# jQuery: namespaces, use variable in another

Tags: jquery, namespaces

I need your help.
How can I use variables in namespaces?
Something like this:

```
$.MyScript = {
    script: $("script")
  , dataID: script.data("id")
  , dataColor: script.data("color")
  , Alerting: function alerting(){
        alert(dataColor);
    }
}
$.Myscript.Alerting;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that's not the right way to write a jQuery plugin, if that's what you are trying to do. Consult with [jQuery's Plugins/Authoring docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) to learn the right way.

---

Apart from that, the way you have the code now you can access the `dataColor` by referencing the parent object with the keyword `this`.

I am removing the code from my answer, because you have other issues as well. Look @dfsq's answer for the solution to your issue.

I am just leaving my answer here as a reference to the official docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access `script` property before object is created. You can make use of this pattern instead:

```
$.MyScript = (function() {

    var $script = $("script");

    return {
        script: $script,
        dataID: $script.data("id"),
        dataColor: $script.data("color"),
        alerting: function alerting() {
            alert(this.dataColor);
        }
    }
})();

$.MyScript.alerting();
```

Comment: @JohnSmit Mark your question as solved by [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/165614) as a solution to your question. Just click on the tick on the top left side of this answer (below the votes).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you a more general approach, without involving jQuery.
You can always create your own namespace, and extend it.

Read [this beautiful article](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/) by Addy Osmani for further details.

```
/* define a global var, the root of your namespace */
var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};

/*
 * init and populate your ns inside a immediately invoked function expression
 * you can pass the jQuery object as argument if you need it in your business logic
 * but it is not necessary
 */
(function(ns, $){
    ns.ScriptObject = function($script){
      var $s = $script;

      this.getDataColor = function(){
         return $s.data("color");
      }

      this.getDataId = function(){
         return $s.data("id");
      }

      /* add further methods */
    }


})(myNamespace ,jQuery)
```